# Install Font Awesome in Laravel Using Composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, font-awesome

I install Twitter Bootstrap using `composer` and can easily include the CSS like this:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, when I install Font Awesome using `composer` in the same way, I don't see any CSS files added to that folder. The one CSS file created by Font Awesome is in `/app/vendor/components/font-awesome.`

How do I include the downloaded Font Awesome CSS into HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. Font Awesome is a client-side dependency that's better managed using a client-side dependency management tool such as npm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the downloaded `css` file inside `public/css/` directory and add following line in your view file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
```

And, Make sure your directory structure should like this:

```
public/css/font-awesome.min.css
public/fonts/
```

So that, icon will be displayed properly.